# Running rstudio on linux mint

Tags: r, rstudio, linux-mint

I'm trying to run rstudio on linux mint. The GUI will open but it seems like it won't connect to r-base. I get this message in the terminal:
"TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'window.desktopHooks.notifyRCrashed')"
QIODevice::read: device not open
I have R version 3.2.5 (2016-04-14). Both R and Rstudio are located in urs/lib. I have tried removing both and reinstalling, but still no luck. I have no problems running R from the terminal. Any advice would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Looks like a permission issue . Look here https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/203007656-Rstudio-starts-up-but-only-shows-menus?page=1#community_comment_210307427